# Forex brokers with free API compatible with Node.js

Tags: programming, algorithmic-trading, fx

I have a Forex trading signal generator written in Node.js and now I am looking for a Forex broker with a free Node.js compatible API.

The requirements are simple:

- be able to send new trade orders
- close trades
- get active trades

The orders are the usual stop loss/take profit trades.

Free API meaning, no flat fee charges or big minimum deposit.

Only interested in ECN/STP brokers and ideally the API to work with demo accounts for testing purposes.

Thanks

Comment: This site is for professionals working in the industry, so this question isn't a good fit.

Comment: @LouisMarascio I fail to see your reasoning. I am full-time on this and have been in a different way in the same industry for years. This question requires algo-trading experience with many brokers, seems quite fitting question for this stackexchange.

Comment: http://www.meetup.com/batsig/events/130829582/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predominant protocols/APIs offered by FX ECNs are FIX and ITCH.  So you might want to look out for node.js implementations of these, e.g. [nodefix](https://github.com/falconair/nodefix).

Without that ``extra'' layer, the trading venue that comes closest to your (bulleted) requirements would be [Currenex](http://www.currenex.com/trading_services_api_integration.html) with their STP connectivity, a RESTful API based on [FIXML](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/pg/structure/tech-specs/fix-protocol).  I put `extra' in quotes because it's now up to you to provide a neat internal framework that exposes node.js routines to your generator and FIXML to the Currenex API.

As for your additional constraints, I think they're a bit off-place.  See it from their point of view: Any ECN with liquidity in the interbank league would put *their systems at risk* by offering such a service directly to just about anyone.  And a broker connected to an ECN would somehow have to pass on the connection costs.

So your best bet might be dealers.  They're much more likely to support your scenario (or at least might do in the future), for instance for stocks I've found [Tradeking](https://developers.tradeking.com/documentation/node), a node.js API around FIXML (much like Currenex').  They have an FX marketplace too (broker-dealer by the looks of things), maybe you could ask them to open their API to that.

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://github.com/mForex/mForex.API.TypeScript, it is TypeScript wrapper for their websocket protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/metaapi.cloud-sdk as well. This is an SDK for the MetaApi service [https://metaapi.clou](https://metaapi.cloud)d. It essentially acts as a bridge for communicating with MetaTrader brokers.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/peterszombati/xapi-node

This module may can be used for X-Trade Brokers xStation5 accounts